# c# combobox in datagrid: want to change focus

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

In my WPF `DataGrid`, I have a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, containing a `ComboBox` as `CellEditingTemplate` content:

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ComboBox/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The Bindings in the `ComboBox` and the `TextBlock` are irrelevant to this question. The problem arises when the Selection of the `ComboBox` is changed: The `DataGrid` doesn't leave the edit mode. I can force this by attaching a `SelectionChanged` event handler to the `ComboBox` and forcing `myDataGrid.CommitEdit()` on the `DataGrid`. However, having multiple `DataGrid`s means that I want to identify the *owning* `DataGrid` of the `ComboBox`. However, the `Parent` property is `null` on the `ComboBox` inside the `SelectionChanged` event.

How do I either

- determine the owning DataGrid or
- automatically leave editing mode in some other way when the selection changed?